# Get ancestors of all nodes in a graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, ancestor

I have a Directed Acyclic graph with 2 million nodes and a value attached to each node. For each node I want to take average of all ancestors. The maximum depth would be 5.

The `ancestors` method in `networkx` package gives all ancestors for a single node. I need to find the ancestors for all nodes in my graph. I can definitely loop over all nodes and use `ancestors` to get them for all nodes one by one. But since my graph has many nodes, I don't want to use for loop for that. I was wondering if there is any faster way to get the ancestors for multiple nodes at a same time.

This just an example of a graph if you want to work on:

```
import networkx as nx
DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (3,4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)])
```

This loop would work but it is not fast and efficient for the size of my graph:

```
ancestors = {node: nx.ancestors(DG, node) for node in DG.nodes}
```

I know the graph already has the information I want and the above solution does lots of redundant computation. So, I would appreciate it if you could give a right function to do this for me. I know the issue, I don't know the solution.

Comment: It's probably not worth using `ancestors` at all, because once you have the ancestors for one node, you pretty much have the ancestors for all the adjacent nodes as well. Start with the root(s), and work your way out.

Comment: @chepner can you please clarify more?

Comment: The ancestor relation is transitive: if `a` is an ancestor of `b` and `b` is an ancestor of `c`, then `a` is an ancestor of `c`. If you use `ancestors` to compute the ancestors for a given node, you've already done most of the work for computing the ancestors of each of the immediate descendants as well. A single call to a hypothetical `all_ancestors` function could be *far* more efficient than simply calling `ancestors` once per node.

Comment: Please tell us what your performance requirement is.  What is the longest time that you wo= would be acceptable to calculate the average of every node's ancestor values in a 5 deep 2 million node network.

Comment: @chepner.  You are assuming the graph is a tree, or a forest.  But it seems possible that there may be more than one path between a pair of nodes, so working your way out from  a root will result in some nodes being visited more than once.  The situation becomes more intractable if the graph contains cycles.

Comment: @user21143831 The only way to shave off some computation time is to ensure that the graph meets some strict constraints.  It must be directed, acyclic and no two nodes can be connected by more than one path - more or less a tree or a forest of unconnected trees.  Checking that a 2million node graph meets these constraints is a lot of work - so you might well take a deep breath and do things by checking the ancestors of every node individually.  In C++ a 2million node graph can check every node ancestor to a depth of 5 in an hour or so.  Python will take longer.

Comment: @ravenspoint the restrictions you mentioned are actually satisfied in my graph. I can create a function not to visit a node twice, but to get the best result I need to sort the nodes by number of their ancestors. Do you know What the fastest way is to sort it?

Comment: How do you know the graph satisfies the constraints?

Comment: It's just nature of my graph.

Comment: Oh well, that all right then!

Answer (score 0):

There is very little point in storing somewhere the the ancestors of every node.  This information would be redundant and require almost as much memory as the graph itself, depending on how deep your graph is.

For most uses, the information is already efficiently stored in the graph.

Here is some C++ code to average the values of a nodes ancestors to a depth of 5:

https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/38cf5f449aa6ef09c157cdc26fa4490273f2d902/src/graphex.cpp#L121-L173

Timing results for running this on 1000 randomly selected nodes on graphs of different sizes:

| graph node count | nodes run | total time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4,700 | 1000 | 2.5 secs |
| 144,650 | 1000 | 613 secs |

Linear ( !? ) extrapolation to a complete run of a 2 million node network gives an estimation of total expected run time : 18 hours

Extrapolation details:

Increasing node count factor 145,000 / 5,000 = 30
Increasing time factor 600 / 2.5 = 240

Ratio : 240 / 30 = 8

Increasing node count 2,000,000 / 150,000 = 13

8 * 13 * 600 secs = 64,000secs = 18 hours

Note: all calculations very approximate and assume the number of 5 deep ancestors per node is constant with respect to total node count ( scalable graph )

Comment: I have a value attached to each node. For each node I want to take average of all ancestors.

Comment: I added more info to the question. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: How did you extrapolate the expected time? I got something like 2.5 hours.

Comment: Calculation details added.